# Regular expression to satisfy 3 out of 4 conditions for password field

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I have to create a regular expression for a password field. The below is the criteria for the same:

- Must be at least ten (10) characters in length
- Must contain at least **three** of the following: Upper case letters, lowercase letters, numbers, and special characters (symbols or punctuation except '<' and '>' )
- Cannot contain more than two identical characters following each other

I am new to this regular expression and need your help here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48345922/3600709)

Answer (score -1):

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^(?!.*(.)\1\1)
(?=.*\d) //should contain at least one digit
(?=.*[a-z]) //should contain at least one lower case
(?=.*[A-Z]) //should contain at least one upper case
[0-9a-zA-Z]{10,20}$");  //should contain at least 8 characters and maximum of 20
```

try this one

Comment: Not sure that does the same thing. For example, this would block me for any password that doesn't contain a digit, even if I had uppercase, lowercase, and a special.

Comment: Thanks for looking in to this. But this is not fully satisfying my criteria. The important part which i am looking for is "Must contain at least three of the following: Upper case letters, lowercase letters, numbers, and special characters (symbols or punctuation except '<' and '>' )".